# Ajax response received in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome:

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

For some reason the following code works in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome or Firefox.
in this browsers I receive the:

> "Not able to retrieve sliders data."

alert.

I would love for some help with this one.

Thanks.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>

if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") 
{ 
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
}
if (request == null)
    alert ("Your browser doesn't support XMLHttpRequest");

function getSelectedText(elementId) 
{
var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
    return null;

return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
}

function sendRequest()
{
    debugger;
    var type = getSelectedText('dropdown');
    //alert("The chosen type: "+type);
    var url = 'https://tomcat-emildesign.rhcloud.com/coupons/Client/serveranswer.jsp?type=' + type;
    request.open("GET", url, true); 
    request.onreadystatechange= processRequest; 
    request.send(null);
}

function processRequest() 
{
    if (request.readyState == 4) 
    {
        if (request.status == 200) 
        {
            parseMessage();
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert ( "Not able to retrieve sliders data." );
        }
    }
}

function parseMessage()
{
    // Assign the XML file to a var variable.
    var doc = request.responseXML; 
    var pending, hires, rejected;
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
        pending = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('pending').item(0).text;
        hires = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('hires').item(0).text;
        rejected =  doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('rejected').item(0).text;      
    }
    else
    {   
        pending = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('pending')[0].textContent;   
        hires = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('hires')[0].textContent;
        rejected = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('rejected')[0].textContent;
    }
    alert("values:" + pending + "," + hires + "," + rejected);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you using a framework like `JQuery`, that'll solve 100s of your cross browser issue.

Comment: @xFortyFourx funny that you mention that, there's a major issue with ajax in the current jQuery release

Comment: @Christophe hmm, I'm unaware of that.

Comment: @xFortyFourx that's my point, using a library blindly is not a solution

Comment: Guys please, I'm not looking for an alternative, I'm looking for a resolution for my problem. I can see the result in the browser when I access the server side link but for some reason i can't retrieve it from the response in this browsers. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you tried investigating the `request` for what error occured? On a side note, having a global `request` variable is an **awful** idea as multiple requests will overwrite each other's responses.

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to investigate the request for the error. It will be great if you could provide an explanation. And thanks for the tip.

Comment: I think @jbabey is referring to the request status, something like this: alert ( "Not able to retrieve sliders data. Request status: " + request.status );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. The issue might be that you are doing a cross-domain request that is trusted in Internet Explorer but fails in other browsers.

To confirm this, you can check if the returned request.status is equal to 0.

More info on the same origin policy on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: can it be allowed in those browsers for development purposes?

Comment: I don't think so. Some servers support CORS or JSONP, this would be the only way to make the client side ajax request work.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace your first if-else block with this:

```
// Mozilla/Safari/Non-IE
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
// IE
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

Your better off testing for support of a function versus testing for the browser.

Comment: Thanks but it's actually the same code. Your just preform your check using the window object while it may resolve problems some one may encounter in Internet Explorer for Chrome the result is the same.